# How can I define a char variable within a method?

Tags: java, variables, char

I'm attempting to write a loop, that when the user inputs Y, the loop continues, and when the user inputs N, the loop stops. However, when I try to assign the variable I get the error "Cannot convert from void to char" I'm obviously messing up somewhere along the line but I'm not sure where.

````
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SimpleList {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    
        System.out.println("Welcome to the Simple List Class");
        
        getData();  
        
    }
    private static void getData() {
        
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        float[] numbers = new float[10];
        
        System.out.println("Enter a non-negative floating point value: ");
        
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            float x = input.nextFloat();
            if (x > 0) {
                numbers[i] = x;
                char ans = System.out.print("Would you like to input another value? (Y or N)? ");
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("That is not a valid. Try Again.");
            }
        
        }
        
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(numbers));
        
        }
        
    } ```
````

Comment: `System.out.print` doesn't return anything. You'll need to use your `Scanner` to get the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're assigning `ans` to the result of `System.out.print()` which is a void method.

Instead, create the prompt beforehand and use the `Scanner` to take the input:

```
public class SimpleList {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    
        System.out.println("Welcome to the Simple List Class");
        
        getData();  
        
    }

    private static void getData() {
        
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        float[] numbers = new float[10];
        
        System.out.println("Enter a non-negative floating point value: ");
        
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            float x = input.nextFloat();
            if (x > 0) {
                numbers[i] = x;

                // New Prompt
                System.out.print("Would you like to input another value? (Y or N)? ");
                // Take input and set ans
                char ans = input.next().charAt(0);
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("That is not a valid. Try Again.");
            }
        
        }
        
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(numbers));
        
    }
        
}
```